# Highlighted theorem in beamer?

Tags: beamer, themes, beamer-metropolis

I like this particular theme called "Metropolis". Here is the sample code, I want theorem to be boxed in certain colors (like the one we get when we use Berkeley theme).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\title{Metropolis}
\subtitle{A modern beamer theme}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Center for modern beamer themes}
% \titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo.pdf}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\section{Introduction}

\begin{theorem} $A = B \implies B=A$

\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=mDarkTeal!30}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=mDarkTeal,fg=black!2}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{theorem}
$A = B \implies B=A$
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh You're welcome!